# Echoing PHP into a JS variable stops rest of script from executing?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to echo a PHP variable into my script, however it seems to break the rest of the script:

**Here's my PHP:**

```
$geo_options = "<option value=\"0\">Select country</option>
<option value=\"AF\">Afghanistan</option>
<option value=\"AL\">Albania</option>
<option value=\"DZ\">Algeria</option>
<option value=\"AS\">American Samoa</option>
<option value=\"AD\">Andorra</option>
<option value=\"AG\">Angola</option>
...";
```

**And my Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var id = $(this).val();

    function countProperties(obj) {
      var prop;
      var propCount = 0;

      for (prop in obj) {
        propCount++;
      }
      return propCount;
    }
      var options = "<?php echo $geo_options; ?>";
      $('#geo-location').append(options);
      $.get('json.php',
        function(data) {
            $('input[name=url]').val(data.url);
            $('select[name=r_id]').prepend("<option selected='selected' value='" + data.rid + "'>" + data.rname + "</option>");
            $('input[name=r_min]').val(data.rmin); $('input[name=r_max]').val(data.rmax);
            if(data.blank == 1) {
            $('input[name=blank]').attr("checked", "checked"); 
            }

            var geo = (countProperties(data)-5)/2;


            }, 'json');

    });
```

If I comment out `var options = '<?php echo $geo_options; ?>';` so this must be the part stopping the rest of the script from executing correctly (from that point downwards, as even `$('#geo-location').append();` doesn't work).

I just can't figure out why this would be though?

Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

*(Note: I've attempted to use both `'` single quotes and `"` double quotes to encase the variable, thinking that the escapes in the string might be the problem, but neither have made a difference).*

**Update:**

I've now placed my entire code, both JS and HTML into a JSFiddle as I figure there might be something I haven't spotted at all. To recap on what I've tried so far; using different quote types (single, double, none), re-escaping the variable `$geo_options` with `add_slashes()`, `str_replace()` and `json_encode()`, echoing the variable `$geo_options` into a random HTML element, which worked fine.

My JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SFwB6/

I must confess, I'm totally stumped.

**Update 2:**

I've attempted to make it much easier, and place the entire `$geo_options` string in `var options` from the beginning; http://jsfiddle.net/NUCRG/.

However, both JSLint and Dreamweaver display a syntax error, but I'm not sure why. Perhaps this is the root of the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to do a var_dump?

Comment: Did you try to ommit the quotes that wrap the <?php ?>, too ? I'm pretty sure it's about the quotes. Or did you ever try setting $geo_options to something simple like <span>hello</span> ?

Comment: I don't get any error's displayed, simply the rest of the script doesn't run, i.e. nothings placed inside `#geo-location`, and the elements that would be affected by the AJAX call, aren't. Are there some kind of system error log that I could turn on for JavaScript? Dreamweaver CS 5.5 displays no syntax errors, but I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: @Clive, I don't really get what you mean if I'm honest. The javascript sits between `<script>` tags, and I'm echoing PHP into it, as I would into any HTML element. Whether this is considered server-side or not I don't know, as I used to think that JS/HTML = client-side only aside from AJAX for requests, but I've recently heard about node.js etc etc.

Comment: @danontheline Tried both. The second worked, just echoing it in between HTML tags, the first (omitting the quotes) didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you need to sets of escapes, when you only have one.
When you echo that string into the javascript, because the string is encapsulated with double quotes (`"`), this means that each occurence of `\"` in the string is just printed as `"`, because the `\` is being removed as an escape character in php.

But then javascript comes up, and also needs that escape character because you are, again encapsulating it in a string.

So to print it, use something like
`var options = "<?php echo str_replace('"', '\"', $geo_options); ?>";`

EDIT:
If you want to go the json route, try this:

```
var options = <?php echo json_encode($geo_options); ?>;
for (var i in options)
    $('#geo-location').append('<option name="'+i+'">'+options[i]+'</option>');
```

Instead of

```
var options = "<?php echo $geo_options; ?>";
$('#geo-location').append(options);
```

Note, the php array `geo_options` will need to look something like:

```
$geo_options = array ("0"=>"Select country",
"AF"=>"Afghanistan",
"AL"=>"Albania",
"DZ"=>"Algeria",
"AS"=>"American Samoa",
"AD"=>"Andorra",
"AG"=>"Angola");
```

EDIT 2:
Alright then, try this

```
var options = '<?php echo str_replace(array("\n","\r"), '', $geo_options); ?>';
```

and make sure the $geo_options string is formatted like (and there are NO single quotes allowed):

```
<option value="0">Select country</option>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AD">Andorra</option>
<option value="AG">Angola</option>
```

Comment: Sounds like a pretty good explanation, but I tried to no avail. Thanks anyway :).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I'm not really looking to go down that route. I only threw it in there because someone else mentioned it, but reformatting the entire string of 200 and something countries is a very long task. I've tried to make it a little more easier, by placing it into a JS variable from the beginning, which still shows a syntax error, which I find rather interesting - http://jsfiddle.net/NUCRG/, but don't understand why?

Comment: YAYYYYYYYYYYYYYY! Thank you so much :). Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to update `var options = "<?php echo $geo_options; ?>";` with `var options = "<?php echo addslashes($geo_options); ?>";` because the \ in your php code only escapes it there, it doesn't save it with it.

Also, you might need to put it all on one line.

Comment: `addslashes();` is passe. Try `json_encode();`. Works better for code obfuscation too!

(I kid, but seriously, consider using `json_encode();` instead of `addslashes();`)

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'm completely stumped, I'll post up my **ENTIRE** code as a JSFiddle to see if anyone can see if there's anything obvious that I'm missing.